# Error when try to access multiple model attribute in thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have two model attributes created in controller. When i want to access one of the model attribute that's not working. There is no error but i don't get result that i want

**This is my controller method :**

```java
@RequestMapping(value = {"/jobList/applyJob/{id}"}, method = 
RequestMethod.GET)
public String applyJob(@PathVariable("id") Integer id,Model model) 
{
    Applicant applicant=new Applicant();
    model.addAttribute("applicantRegister",applicant);
    model.addAttribute("selectedJob",jobService.findById(id));
    return "apply";
}
```

**And this is my apply.html :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras- 
springsecurity3">
<head>
<title>Hello World!</title>
</head>

<p  th:value="${selectedJob.jobTitle}">

<form method="post" th:action="@{/jobList/applicantRegister}">
Name:<br>
<input type="text" th:field="${applicantRegister.name}"><br>
Email:<br>
<input type="text" th:field="${applicantRegister.email}"><br>
Phone:<br>
<input type="text" th:field="${applicantRegister.phone}"><br>
Address:<br>
<input type="text" th:field="${applicantRegister.address}"><br>
Thoughts On Job:<br>
<input type="text" th:field="${applicantRegister.thoughtsOnJob}">

<input type="hidden" th:field="${applicantRegister.fkJobId}" 
th:value="${selectedJob.jobId}"><br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">


</form>

</body>
</html>
```

When i want to access selectedJob properties in apply.html file that's return null. But when i was debugging,line:

```java
model.addAttribute("selectedJob",jobService.findById(id));
```

works perfect.

Where am I making a mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

`<p>` HTML Tag has no `value` attribute. You must use `text`:

```
<p  th:text="${selectedJob.jobTitle}">
```

Comment: You're right. I fixed that line but still not working.

Comment: What you see if you print `selectedJob` itself? Isn't `jobService` returning Optional or something?

Comment: When i use this line : <input type="text" th:value="${selectedJob.jobId}"/> that show me the right value in input text, but with this line: <input type="text" th:field="${applicantRegister.fkJobId}" th:value="${selectedJob.jobId}"/> input text is empty.

Comment: You can not use `th:field` and `th:value` together. Instead use `th:value`, `th:name` and `th:id`: `<input type="text" th:name="${applicantRegister.fkJobId}"  th:id="${applicantRegister.fkJobId}" th:value="${selectedJob.jobId}"/>`

Comment: I try this but now cannot submit form.